# how to find whether a string is contained in another string

Tags: python, string

```
a='1234;5'
print a.index('s')
```

the error is :

```
> "D:\Python25\pythonw.exe"  "D:\zjm_code\kml\a.py" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\zjm_code\kml\a.py", line 4, in <module>
    print a.index('s')
ValueError: substring not found
```

thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-method

Comment: a string in another string ? you said it. this is python

Comment: @Anderson: agree, It should be closed as duplicated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try using `find()` instead - this will tell you where it is in the string:

```
a = '1234;5'
index = a.find('s')
if index == -1:
    print "Not found."
else:
    print "Found at index", index
```

If you just want to know *whether* the string is in there, you can use `in`:

```
>>> print 's' in a
False
>>> print 's' not in a
True
```

Answer (score 13):

```
print ('s' in a)     # False
print ('1234' in a)  # True
```

Use `find` if you need the index as well, but don't want an exception be raised.

```
print a.find('s')    # -1
print a.find('1234') # 0
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use `in` operator if you just want to check whether a substring is in a string.

```
if "s" in mystring:
   print "do something"
```

otherwise, you can use `find()` and check for -1 (not found) or using `index()`

Answer (score 5):

`str.find()` and `str.index()` are nearly identical. the biggest difference is that when a string is not found, `str.index()` throws an error, like the one you got, while `str.find()` returns -1 as others' have posted.

there are 2 sister methods called `str.rfind()` and `str.rindex()` which start the search from the end of the string and work their way towards the beginning.

in addition, as others have already shown, the **`in`** operator (as well as **`not in`**) are perfectly valid as well.

finally, if you're trying to look for *patterns* within strings, you may consider regular expressions, although i think too many people use them when they're overkill. in other (famous) words, "[now you have *two* problems](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)."

that's it as far as all the info i have for now. however, if you are learning Python and/or learning programming, one highly useful exercise i give to my students is to try and build `*find()` and `*index()` in Python code yourself, or even **`in`** and **`not in`** (although as functions). you'll get good practice traversing through strings, *and* you'll have a better understanding as far as how the existing string methods work.

good luck!

Comment: Regular Expressions a Overkill?! Why? There's probably no more efficient and clear way of programming most string matching algorithms.

Comment: For simple searches that can be done with tools like find() and index(), regular expressions are not as good a choice because they tend to be difficult to read without careful inspection.  It's rare to be able to skim past a regexp and catch all the details of what it's trying to do. They can be very efficient for complex patterns but maintainability can be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this according to below mentioned.

method 1:

```
if string.find("substring") == -1:
 print("found")
else:
 print("not found")
```

Method 2:

```
 if "substring" in "string":
  print("found")
 else:
   print("not found")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def substr(s1, s2):  # s1='abc' , s2 = 'abcd'
    i = 0
    cnt = 0
    s = ''
    while i < len(s2):
        if cnt < len(s1):
            if s1[cnt] == s2[i]:
                cnt += 1
                s += s2[i]
            else:
                cnt = 0
                s = ''
        i += 1
    if s == s1:
        print(f'{s1} is substring of {s2}')
    else:
        print(f'{s1} is not a substring of {s2}')
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: if one string containing another string as a substring. That's the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way of checking whether a substring is present in a string or not.

```py
def sea(str,str1):
    if (str1[0:] in str):
        return "yes"
    else:
        return "no"

print(sea("sahil", "ah"))
```