# Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?

Tags: python, string, substring, contains

I'm looking for a `string.contains` or `string.indexof` method in Python.

I want to do:

```
if not somestring.contains("blah"):
   continue
```

Answer (score 8368, accepted):

Use the [`in` operator](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details):

```
if "blah" not in somestring: 
    continue
```

Note: This is case-sensitive.

Comment: Note: This is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 908):

If it's just a substring search you can use `string.find("substring")`.

You do have to be a little careful with [`find`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), [`index`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.index), and [`in`](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) though, as they are substring searches. In other words, this:

```
s = "This be a string"
if s.find("is") == -1:
    print("No 'is' here!")
else:
    print("Found 'is' in the string.")
```

It would print `Found 'is' in the string.` Similarly, `if "is" in s:` would evaluate to `True`. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: +1 for highlighting the gotchas involved in substring searches. the obvious solution is `if ' is ' in s:` which will return `False` as is (probably) expected.

Comment: @aaronasterling Obvious it may be, but not entirely correct. What if you have punctuation or it's at the start or end? What about capitalisation? Better would be a case insensitive regex search for `\bis\b` (word boundaries).

Comment: Why would this not be what the OP wants

Comment: @uh_big_mike_boi The problem with substring searches is that, in this example, you're looking for the word **`is`** inside "This be a string." That will evaluate to True because of the `is` in `This`. This is bad for programs that search for words, like swear filters (for example, a dumb word check for "ass" would also catch "grass").

Answer (score 523):

> ### Does Python have a string contains substring method?

**99%** of use cases will be covered using the keyword, `in`, which returns `True` or `False`:

```py
'substring' in any_string
```

For the use case of getting the index, use `str.find` (which returns -1 on failure, and has optional positional arguments):

```py
start = 0
stop = len(any_string)
any_string.find('substring', start, stop)
```

or `str.index` (like `find` but raises ValueError on failure):

```py
start = 100 
end = 1000
any_string.index('substring', start, end)
```

### Explanation

Use the `in` comparison operator because

1. the language intends its usage, and
2. other Python programmers will expect you to use it.

```py
>>> 'foo' in '**foo**'
True
```

The opposite (complement), which the original question asked for, is `not in`:

```py
>>> 'foo' not in '**foo**' # returns False
False
```

This is semantically the same as `not 'foo' in '**foo**'` but it's much more readable and explicitly provided for in the language as a readability improvement.

### Avoid using `__contains__`

The "contains" method implements the behavior for `in`. This example,

```
str.__contains__('**foo**', 'foo')
```

returns `True`. You could also call this function from the instance of the superstring:

```
'**foo**'.__contains__('foo')
```

But don't. Methods that start with underscores are considered semantically non-public. The only reason to use this is when implementing or extending the `in` and `not in` functionality (e.g. if subclassing `str`):

```
class NoisyString(str):
    def __contains__(self, other):
        print(f'testing if "{other}" in "{self}"')
        return super(NoisyString, self).__contains__(other)

ns = NoisyString('a string with a substring inside')
```

and now:

```
>>> 'substring' in ns
testing if "substring" in "a string with a substring inside"
True
```

### Don't use `find` and `index` to test for "contains"

Don't use the following string methods to test for "contains":

```
>>> '**foo**'.index('foo')
2
>>> '**foo**'.find('foo')
2

>>> '**oo**'.find('foo')
-1
>>> '**oo**'.index('foo')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#40>", line 1, in <module>
    '**oo**'.index('foo')
ValueError: substring not found
```

Other languages may have no methods to directly test for substrings, and so you would have to use these types of methods, but with Python, it is much more efficient to use the `in` comparison operator.

Also, these are not drop-in replacements for `in`. You may have to handle the exception or `-1` cases, and if they return `0` (because they found the substring at the beginning) the boolean interpretation is `False` instead of `True`.

If you really mean `not any_string.startswith(substring)` then say it.

### Performance comparisons

We can compare various ways of accomplishing the same goal.

```
import timeit

def in_(s, other):
    return other in s

def contains(s, other):
    return s.__contains__(other)

def find(s, other):
    return s.find(other) != -1

def index(s, other):
    try:
        s.index(other)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True



perf_dict = {
'in:True': min(timeit.repeat(lambda: in_('superstring', 'str'))),
'in:False': min(timeit.repeat(lambda: in_('superstring', 'not'))),
'__contains__:True': min(timeit.repeat(lambda: contains('superstring', 'str'))),
'__contains__:False': min(timeit.repeat(lambda: contains('superstring', 'not'))),
'find:True': min(timeit.repeat(lambda: find('superstring', 'str'))),
'find:False': min(timeit.repeat(lambda: find('superstring', 'not'))),
'index:True': min(timeit.repeat(lambda: index('superstring', 'str'))),
'index:False': min(timeit.repeat(lambda: index('superstring', 'not'))),
}
```

And now we see that using `in` is much faster than the others.
Less time to do an equivalent operation is better:

```
>>> perf_dict
{'in:True': 0.16450627865128808,
 'in:False': 0.1609668098178645,
 '__contains__:True': 0.24355481654697542,
 '__contains__:False': 0.24382793854783813,
 'find:True': 0.3067379407923454,
 'find:False': 0.29860888058124146,
 'index:True': 0.29647137792585454,
 'index:False': 0.5502287584545229}
```

#### How can `in` be faster than `__contains__` if `in` uses `__contains__`?

This is a fine follow-on question.

Let's disassemble functions with the methods of interest:

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(lambda: 'a' in 'b')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a')
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('b')
              4 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis(lambda: 'b'.__contains__('a'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('b')
              2 LOAD_METHOD              0 (__contains__)
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 ('a')
              6 CALL_METHOD              1
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

so we see that the `.__contains__` method has to be separately looked up and then called from the Python virtual machine - this should adequately explain the difference.

Comment: Why should one avoid `str.index` and `str.find`? How else would you suggest someone find the index of a substring instead of just whether it exists or not? (or did you mean avoid using them in place of contains - so don't use `s.find(ss) != -1` instead of `ss in s`?)

Comment: Precisely so, although the intent behind the use of those methods may be better addressed by elegant use of the `re` module. I have not yet found a use for str.index or str.find myself in any code I have written yet.

Comment: Please extend your answer to advice against using `str.count` as well (`string.count(something) != 0`). *shudder*

Comment: How does the [`operator` module version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.contains) perform?

Comment: @jpmc26 it's the same as `in_` above - but with a stackframe around it, so it's slower than that: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/operator.py#L153

Comment: I would just add that `__contains__` can also be used for custom (non-string) classes for implementing some cools behaviors. For instance, you could create a Pizza class and create a `__contains__` method to allow things like `if Ingredient("pepper") in Pizza("margherita")` with some internal checking. It could also be used for subclassing lists, or any iterable element (for instance, to check if a specific date is included in a date range).

Answer (score 197):

`if needle in haystack:` is the normal use, as @Michael says -- it relies on the [`in`](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) operator, more readable and faster than a method call.

If you truly need a method instead of an operator (e.g. to do some weird `key=` for a very peculiar sort...?), that would be [`'haystack'.__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__).  But since your example is for use in an `if`, I guess you don't really mean what you say;-).  It's not good form (nor readable, nor efficient) to use special methods directly -- they're meant to be used, instead, through the operators and builtins that delegate to them.

Comment: How much faster than a method call?

Answer (score 138):

## `in` Python strings and lists

Here are a few useful examples that speak for themselves concerning the `in` method:

```
>>> "foo" in "foobar"
True
>>> "foo" in "Foobar"
False
>>> "foo" in "Foobar".lower()
True
>>> "foo".capitalize() in "Foobar"
True
>>> "foo" in ["bar", "foo", "foobar"]
True
>>> "foo" in ["fo", "o", "foobar"]
False
>>> ["foo" in a for a in ["fo", "o", "foobar"]]
[False, False, True]
```

Caveat. Lists are iterables, and the `in` method acts on iterables, not just strings.

If you want to compare strings in a more fuzzy way to measure how "alike" they are, consider using the Levenshtein package

[Here's an answer that shows how it works.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69545740/3730397)

Answer (score 56):

If you are happy with `"blah" in somestring` but want it to be a function/method call, you can probably do this

```
import operator

if not operator.contains(somestring, "blah"):
    continue
```

All operators in Python can be more or less found in the [operator module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#operator.contains) including `in`.

Answer (score 54):

So apparently there is nothing similar for vector-wise comparison. An obvious Python way to do so would be:

```
names = ['bob', 'john', 'mike']
any(st in 'bob and john' for st in names) 
>> True

any(st in 'mary and jane' for st in names) 
>> False
```

Comment: That's because there is a bajillion ways of creating a Product from atomic variables.  You can stuff them in a tuple, a list (which are forms of Cartesian Products and come with an implied order), or they can be named properties of a class (no a priori order) or dictionary values, or they can be files in a directory, or whatever.  Whenever you can uniquely identify (iter or getitem) something in a 'container' or 'context', you can see that 'container' as a sort of vector and define binary ops on it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category#Free_strict_monoidal_category

Comment: Worth nothing that `in` should not be used with lists because it does a linear scan of the elements and is slow compared. Use a set instead, especially if membership tests are to be done repeatedly.

Answer (score 33):

You can use `y.count()`.

It will return the integer value of the number of times a substring appears in a string.

For example:

```
string.count("bah")   # gives 0
string.count("Hello") # gives 1
```

Comment: counting a string is costly when you just want to _check_ if it's there...

Comment: I agree, I had an in depth answer that proposed 3 possible solutions. but this was changed by Jean-Francois Fabre to be what it currently is. Not sure why he would change it so.

Comment: Shifting right is almost certainly not what you want to do here.

Comment: This is just not the answer to the question. It is by no means an idiomatic way to find out if a string is in another string

Comment: @rsandwick3: I think OP only means ">>" to denote "gives the result", like "->" or "==>". I edited to clarify.

Answer (score 26):

Here is your answer:

```
if "insert_char_or_string_here" in "insert_string_to_search_here":
    #DOSTUFF
```

For checking if it is false:

```
if not "insert_char_or_string_here" in "insert_string_to_search_here":
    #DOSTUFF
```

OR:

```
if "insert_char_or_string_here" not in "insert_string_to_search_here":
    #DOSTUFF
```

Comment: PEP 8 prefers "if x not in y" to "if not x in y".

Answer (score 12):

You can use regular expressions to get the occurrences:

```
>>> import re
>>> print(re.findall(r'( |t)', to_search_in)) # searches for t or space
['t', ' ', 't', ' ', ' ']
```

Comment: It is actually less efficient in terms of time complexity. You are better off using the ``in`` operator. But it's a fun solution. In case you insist of using ``re``, ``re.match`` is better to use as boolean.