# What's wrong with the IF some words IN a string

Tags: python

[How to check a string for specific characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188792/how-to-check-a-string-for-specific-characters)
I find the link is very useful. But what's wrong with my codes?

```
string = "A17_B_C_S.txt"

if ("M.txt" and "17") in string:
    print True
else:
    print False
```

and the answer always comes out

```
True
```

Comment: Closely related: [if x or y or z == blah](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125)

Comment: Don't use `if some_boolean_test: print True; else: print False` when just `print some_boolean_test` will do.

Comment: +1 this is a common trap when moving from existing figures of "speech" to own constructs without fully grasping the full implications of each subelement, absolutely legitimate question IMO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your `and` evaluates to `17` which is in `stringList`. The `and` evaluates to 17 because of short circuiting.

```
>>> "M.txt" and "17"
'17'
```

Python evaluates non empty strings to the value `True`. Hence, `M.txt` evaluates to `True`, thus the value of the expression depends on the second value which is returned(`17`) and is found in the `stringList`. (Why? When `and` is performed with a `True` value, the value of the expression depends on the second value, if it's `False`, the value of the expression is `False`, else, it's `True`.)

You need to change your expression to

```
if "M.txt" in stringList and "17" in stringList:
    #...
```

Or use the builtin [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)

```
if all(elem in stringList for elem in ["M.txt", "17"]):
    #...
```

Comment: Very clear explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
stringList = "A17_B_C_S.txt"

if "M.txt" in stringList and "17" in stringList:
    print True
else:
    print False

>>> 
True
```

`('M.txt' and '17')` returns `'17'`. So you are just testing `'17' in stringList`.

```
>>> ('M.txt' and '17')
'17'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because

```
("M.txt" and "17") in string
```

doesn't mean what it may *sound* like. In python, it means:

> test if a value, you'll get when performing boolean and between
>   "M.txt" and "17", is found inside a 'string'

`and` in your code performs not only the `and` operator, but also returns the final term, which is `"17"`. Therefore ("M.txt" and "17") will return "17", and so it will in fact only test if `"17"` is in a `string`

If what you actually wanted was:

> test if there is "M.txt" in string and also "17" in string

you have to write:

```
if "M.txt" in string and "17" in string:
```

Answer (score 1):

`("M.txt" and "17")` returns `"17"` because it evaluates to `(True and True)` (`bool("M.txt") == True`). Thus, the second one is chosen.

Then you're trying to say `if "17" in string`.

You have to individually compare the items:

```
if "M.txt" in stringList and "17" in stringList:
```

Or even:

```
if all(i in stringList for i in ("M.txt", "17")):
```