# How to check if some characters are in a string using Boolean?

Tags: python, string, boolean, character

If I want to know whether some characters are found in a string, how? String will be returned as Boolean. The body is as below :

Return `True` if the letters 'A', 'T', 'C' or 'G' are found in the string. Return `False` if it is not.

def is_valid_sequence(dna):

```
>>> is_valid_sequence('ATCG')
True

>>> is_valid_sequence('AtcGEQ')
False
```

How to write the code? Thank you.

Comment: Can you *honestly* get no further than the definition line? This isn't a code-writing service - try reading [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/). Also, shouldn't that be *"Return `True` if **only** the letters `'A'`, `'T'`, `'C'` or `'G'` are found in the string."*?

Comment: `G` is in your second string.

Comment: This question has already been answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188792/how-to-check-a-string-for-specific-characters

Comment: @Nike, why would you need re?

Comment: @jornsharpe I'm sorry. Just that I didn't post the code I written.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in this answer - [How to check a string for specific characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188792/how-to-check-a-string-for-specific-characters)

```
def is_valid(dna)
    if 'A' or 'T' or 'G' or 'C' in dna:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question uses    `'A', 'T', 'C' or 'G'` but your output suggests it should be `'A', 'T', 'C' and 'G'` so you can use `all` to check that every `char` in `l`  is in your string:

```
l = [ 'A', 'T', 'C' ,'G']
s = 'AtcGEQ'

print all(x in s for x in l)
False

s='ATCG'
print all(x in s for x in l)
True
```

If you want to check if  `'A' or  'T' or  'C' or 'G'` is in s:

```
l = [ 'A', 'T', 'C' ,'G']
s= 'AtcGEQ'

print any(x in s for x in l)
True
```

But that will not match what you have in your question:

```
>>> is_valid_sequence('AtcGEQ')
False
```

Comment: Is it possible for the code to work : 
i = 0
    while i < len(dna):
        dna[i] == 'A' or 'T' or 'C' or 'G'
It seems that it works if it is true, but it return T when it's not true. Anything wrong?

Comment: you need to use something like  `if dna[i] == 'A' or dna[i] == 'T' or dna[i] ==  'C' or dna[i] ==  'G'` Do you want any to match or do all have to match. You should also add what you tried to your question.

Answer (score 0):

A string contains a valid DNA sequence if *only* the letters `ATCG` appear in the string (though not necessarily *all* of them - you could have a gene sequence that doesn't have a `C` anywhere, although that's of course unlikely).

With that in mind, the function should be

```
def is_valid_sequence(seq):
    return set(seq).issubset({"A", "T", "C", "G"})

>>> is_valid_sequence("AAAATAATG")
True
>>> is_valid_sequence("AAAATAATGX")
False
>>> is_valid_sequence("AAAATACTAATG")
True
```