# How can I access a element from list if its in one number without comma?

Tags: python, list

example: [1233456]

How to access the fourth element? Basically I am taking input from the user, but when I print the length it shows me one and if I put a comma in between the numbers it shows correctly. So I want to access an element from a number as I ask before.

Comment: What does this have to do with `sqldatatypes`?

Comment: Please refer this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116496/python-print-specific-character-from-string

Answer (score 0):

```
int(str(ex[0])[3])
```

The program takes the 1st element of the list(which in your case is '1233456'), converts it into a string(because integers are not subscriptable). Takes the fourth character of the string, which has an index of 3 as indexes in python start at 0.
And finally, converts it back to an integer.

Comment: why are u add ex[0]

Comment: Because the name of the list he created is ex and ex[0] gives you the first element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this resource on Sequential Data Types](https://python-course.eu/python3_sequential_data_types.php) might help you.

When you have `[1233456]` it's actually one single integer as the first element (0) in a list.

If you cast it to a string, you can pick out the individual characters, which you can then cast back to integers with `int()`:

```
>>> my_ints = [1233456]
>>> my_str = str(my_ints[0])
>>> my_str[2]
'3'
>>> int(my_str[2])
3
```

Please remember [2] is the third element of the list, as they are zero-indexed... ;-)

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: if i typcast my list to the integer from string it shows me error ex_ d = int(str(my_lst))

Comment: Hello Chinmay. Please note you can't cast the list to a string. In the example I cast the first element of the list (the integer 1233456) to a string: `str(my_ints[0])`. If you need some help with lists and how they work I would definitely review that link I mentioned!!! :-)