# Creating python scrabble function

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a scrabble function that takes a string of letters and returns the score based on the letters.
This is my code so far:

```
def scrabble_score(rack):
    count = 0
    for letter in rack:
        if letter == "EAIONRTLSU":
            count += 1
            return count
        elif letter == "DG":
            count += 2
            return count
        elif letter == "BCMP":
            count += 3
            return count        
        elif letter == "FHVWY":
            count += 4
            return count
        elif letter == "K":
            count += 5
            return count
        elif letter == "JX":
            count += 8
            return count
        else:
            letter == "QZ"
            count += 10
            return count
```

However when I tried to call the function

```
    scrabble_score("AABBWOL")
```

it returns 10 when it should return 14?

Comment: You're doing a string comparison to check if a letter exists. Use regex instead. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188792/how-to-check-a-string-for-specific-characters)

Comment: ^ expanding on @Dana, the string comparison (`==`) is returning `False` for every `if` so it gets to the last statement, the `else`, where it returns 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has two issues:

- The `return` statement should be called only one time, **after** the `for` iteration ends, so it can sum all the letter values
- each `if` statement should check if the letter is **in** the string, not if it is equal to the list of letters with a specific value.

Then it would look like:

```
def scrabble_score(rack):
    count = 0
    for letter in rack:
        print letter
        if letter in "EAIONRTLSU":
            count += 1
        elif letter in "DG":
            count += 2
        elif letter in "BCMP":
            count += 3
        elif letter in "FHVWY":
            count += 4
        elif letter in "K":
            count += 5
        elif letter in "JX":
            count += 8
        else:
            count += 10
    return count
```

returning: `14`

Comment: The line: `letter in "QZ"` is not actually doing anything useful to the if-else and can be removed entirely