# How to check that none of the chars are in the string?

Tags: python

```
def lookup(content):
    value=True
    if any(x not in content for x in ['A','B','C']):
        value = False
    print (value)
```

What i want is check if any of these `'A' 'B' 'C'` is in a string , for example if string equates `ABCAA` then the value will be true, if the string is `ABDC` then value is wrong because content contains a char not defined in my list above.The issue is i'm getting false with that function for `'ABC'` which isn't supposed to happen.

Comment: `any(x not in ['A','B','C'] for x in content)`

Comment: `all(x in ['A','B','C'] for x in content)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check a string for specific characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188792/how-to-check-a-string-for-specific-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use sets:

```
# input
my_string = 'abcd'

# set of allowed characters
approved_characters = set('abc')

# characters in string that are not in set of approved characters
unapproved_characters = set(my_string) - approved_characters # gives {'d'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def lookup(content):
    print(all(x in ['A','B','C'] for x in content))

lookup('ABC') #output: True
```