# Why does the statement if 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u' in String: execute even when there are no vowels in string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My Code:

```
VowelsInString = False
String = 'bbbb000'
if 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u' in String:
  VowelsInString = True
elif 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u' not in String:
  VowelsInSting = False
```

So, I was expecting that when this ran, the if statement would be skipped and the  VowelsInString would remain False, but upon running the code, the value of VowelsInString is True.

I expect that I may have done something wrong whilst typing the vowel checker if argument as I am fairly new to the concept of reading characters in strings. I would appreciate if someone would help me on debugging this code.

If that however is not the case, than I would, again, appreciate if someone would help on telling me what I've done wrong.

Comment: wow this question got answers quickly

Comment: you could import re and use `if re.search('a|e|i|o|u',string)`

Comment: @Onyambu oh, clever!

Comment: `VowelsInString = any(v in String for v in 'aeiou')` You don't need an `if/elif` for this, it can be done as a one-liner.

Comment: @ZeddCodes_ This is one of the most common duplicate questions on Stack Overflow. It's already got plenty of great answers, but it's so easy to answer that lots of people try to write a new answer anyway every time it comes up.

Answer (score 1):

`'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u' in String:`

evaluates as

`('a') or ('e') or ('i') or ('o') or ('u' in String)`.

Since 'a' is truthy in python, this evaluates to `True`.

You can either write

`if 'a' in String or 'e' in String ...`

or

```
def has_vowel(String):
    for s in String:
        if s in 'aeiou':
            return True
```

or perhaps

`if any(s in String for s in 'aeiou'):`

or (credit to Onyambu):

```
import re
...
re.search('[aeiou]',string)
```

Comment: so instead, i would do if 'a' in String... or 'u' in String?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: You could also use a loop "the other way": for s in string: if s in ['a', 'e' ...]: return true

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: (I can only accept answers after 7 minutes it says)

Comment: No prob, glad to help :)

Comment: Just a query: Did I use 'not' correctly in the elif statement?

Comment: @ZeddCodes_ no. For the same reason. Also, since your `if` condition can only be true or false, you don't need to use `elif` (when there are multiple "else" possibilities), or even `else` (which would be OK to use, but unnecessary since this assignment can be done just by evaluating the boolean expression and assigning that value to the `VowelsInString`.

Comment: You don't need an `if/elif` for this, or even `else`: it can be done in a single expression like: `VowelsInString = any(v in String for v in 'aeiou')`

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions is a tautology:

```
if 'a':
    print("I am always going to print")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are evaluating the character itself as a bool.

It is detecting 'a' as True and returning true.

Try something more like:

```
if any(i in '<string>' for i in ('a','b','c')):
```

see: [How to check a string for specific characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188792/how-to-check-a-string-for-specific-characters)

Comment: You can just do `for i in 'abc'` here, since strings are iterables of their characters. But, while that might be more readable for experienced Python devs, it might be less readable to novices, so I'm not sure whether the tradeoff is worth it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u' in String` is always true. What you meant to do is:

```
if 'a' in String or 'e' in String or ...:
```

Or, using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(c in String for c in 'aeiou'):
```