# Find and check line in python

Tags: python

```
def check():
    with open('cefuse.txt') as f:
        datafile = f.readlines()
    for line in datafile:
        if line starts with 'Word 30' and contains only 0
            return True
    return False
```

I want to check a line in .txt file. If it's contains only 0 then retcode will 1 otherwise 0.

This is my line:

```
Word 30 : 0x01312e58
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check a string for specific characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188792/how-to-check-a-string-for-specific-characters)

Comment: Your description doesn't match your code snippet.

Comment: I suppose you want `if line.startswith('Word 30') and line.split(":")[-1].strip() == '0'`.What does it mean to **contain only 0** ? the line you have also contains `Word 30 :`, do you want to see if it contains something after the `:`?

Comment: My line is Word 30 : 0x01312e58. After Word 30 all characters could be changed. I want to check if they will be 0 then it fails otherwise pass.

Answer (score 1):

I hope your are expecting like this.

```py
def check():
    with open('cefuse.txt') as f:
        datafile = f.readlines()
    for line in datafile:
        if line startswith('Word 30') and '0' in line:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Like that but line can be "Word 30: 0x000000" this is for me fail but if one of the zeros not zero then it's pass.like 0x00200.

Comment: I'm not clear with requirements. Could you please show your expected output? Does your line always start with *word 30 * for true condition?