# Check if string in list contains specific character and if it does only print that specific string from the list

Tags: python, list, if-statement

So let's say I have a list of names and I want to see if they contain the letter "a". How would I go about printing just the strings in the list containing that and not just printing the whole list.

```
Names = ["Mike", "Ted", "John", "Adam", "Liam"]
if ("a" in Names):
     print (//Print out the names containing a//)

else:
     if ("a" not in Names):
     print("No names found containing a")
```

Obviously it's a bit more complicated than this but just to show just a very basic look at what I'm aiming for.

Comment: Do you understand, in general, how to do something `for` each item that is `in` the list? Hint, hint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check a string for specific characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188792/how-to-check-a-string-for-specific-characters)

Comment: you can try ok = [x for x in Names if 'a' in x]. you might want to adjust it to make it more dynamic. but this should show you how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pretty simple:

```py
for i in Names :
  if "a" in i : print( i )
else : print( "No names found" )
```

Comment: Thank you, it's simple I know but I've just started out with this stuff so I appreciate it.

Comment: Okey, sorry, i didn't want to sound offensive :)

Comment: no offense taken, thanks again for your help :)