# not able to apply (filter)if else condition

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I was using scrapy for web scraping, I can grab all elements but my target is to get all the names having reviews greater than 50 , I don't know where I am lacking

```
import scrapy


class TripadSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tripad'
    allowed_domains = ['www.tripadvisor.in']
    start_urls = ['https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g304554-c33-Mumbai_Maharashtra.html']
    first = 'https://www.tripadvisor.in/'

    def parse(self, response):
        for i in response.xpath("//div[@class='_2Q7zqOgW Vt o']"):
            rating = str(i.xpath(".//span[@class='w726Ki5B']/text()").get())

            if rating >= '50':
                title = i.xpath(".//a[@class='_15_ydu6b S5 H4 Cj b']/text()").getall()
                yield {
                    'title':title,
                    'rating':rating
                }
            elif rating == 'None':
                continue

        next_page = response.xpath("//a[@class='nav next rndBtn ui_button primary taLnk']/@href").get()
        if next_page:
            sequence = (self.first,next_page)
            nexturl = ''.join(sequence)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=nexturl,callback=self.parse)
```

can somebody assist me

Comment: convert `rating` to `int` ,  `if int(rating) >= 50:`

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,076   getting this error

Comment: @sittsering the string comparison will still work as when used on strings it will compare lexicographical order

Comment: this script is working for few pages then starts misbehaving

Comment: So with your ValueError it shows the rating is 1,076. When comparing  '1,076' >= '50' , because of the comma, it will not return true. You will need to parse the rating and treat is as an integer

Comment: you can't check the string values as less than or greater than condition. only integer datatype can apply for less than or greater than condition. so you can convert the rating in to int like a if int(rating) >= 50:

Comment: ok then how to remove comma, any idea

Comment: try ```int(float(rating))```. Then you will have to change your if statement to compare integers

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,076'   **if int(float(rating)) >= 50**

Comment: @Dev then what approach should i apply

Comment: you sholud convert the rating value as integer like if int(rating) >= 50:

Comment: Try this in your python console
```rating = ''.join('1,076'.split(','))```
Here you split the value 1,076 into an array ['1', '076'] then join it back with no spaces.
You'll have to check if the rating string contains a comma as this will likely throw an error. Maybe use a try - except to set the rating. Then you just have to parse this string as an integer!

Comment: thanks @sittsering it is working using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188792/how-to-check-a-string-for-specific-characters

Comment: @sb_ that will wont do,i .e,  "101" is less than "50" by string comparison.

Comment: i ahve done it by converting it to int

Answer (score 0):

## Replace Comma with Decimal

```
if type(eval(rating)) == int or type(eval(rating)) == float:
    rating_string_decimal = rating.replace(',','.')
    val = float(rating_string_decimal )
    if round(rating_string_decimal)>= 50:
          title = i.xpath(".//a[@class='_15_ydu6b S5 H4 Cj b']/text()").getall()
                yield {
                    'title':title,
                    'rating':rating
                }
elif rating == 'None':
    continue
```

Comment: buddy it is not working fine

Comment: now check i update the code

Comment: https://dpaste.org/wrnu
this worked for me