# Split a string if character is present else don't split

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `string` like below in `python`

```
testing_abc
```

I want to split string based on `_` and extract the `2` element

I have done like below

```
split_string = string.split('_')[1]
```

I am getting the correct output as expected

```
abc
```

Now I want this to work for below strings

```
1) xyz
```

When I use

```
split_string = string.split('_')[1]
```

I get below error

```
list index out of range
```

expected output I want is `xyz`

```
2) testing_abc_bbc
```

When I use

```
split_string = string.split('_')[1]
```

I get `abc` as output

expected output I want is `abc_bbc`

Basically What I want is

```
1) If string contains `_` then print everything after the first `_` as variable
2) If string doesn't contain `_` then print the string as variable
```

How can I achieve what I want

Comment: `string.split('_', 1)[-1]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the `maxsplit` argument of `split` to `1` and then take the last element of the resulting list.

```py
>>> "testing_abc".split("_", 1)[-1]
'abc'
>>> "xyz".split("_", 1)[-1]
'xyz'
>>> "testing_abc_bbc".split("_", 1)[-1]
'abc_bbc'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list slicing and `str.join` in case `_` is in the string, and you can just get the first element of the split (which is the only element) in the other case:

```
sp = string.split('_')
result = '_'.join(sp[1:]) if len(sp) > 1 else sp[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the ways are good but there is a very simple and optimum way for this.

Try:

```py
s = 'aaabbnkkjbg_gghjkk_ttty'
try:
    ans = s[s.index('_')+1:]
except:
    ans = s
```

Comment: `ans = s[s.index('_')+1:]`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so your error is supposed to happen/expected because you are using `'_'` as your delimiter and it doesn't contain it.
See [How to check a string for specific characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188792/how-to-check-a-string-for-specific-characters) for character checking.

If you want to only split iff the string contains a `'_'` and only on the first  one,

```
input_string = "blah_end"
delimiter = '_'

if delimiter in input_string:
     result = input_string.split("_", 1)[1] # The ",1" says only split once
else:
     # Do whatever here. If you want  a space, " " to be a delimiter too you can try that.
     result = input_string
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will solve your problem

```
txt = "apple_banana_cherry_orange"
# setting the maxsplit parameter to 1, will return a list with 2 elements!
x = txt.split("_", 1)
print(x[-1])
```