# How to handle symbols in Python?

Tags: python

How can I regroup all the symbols like `"!@#$%^&*()_+[]{}'\"|./?><"` and use them, if the variable contains the symbols it will return `False`?

I'm trying to create a code for the password, and if the password contains only symbols like `"!@#$%^&*()_+[]{}'\"|./?><"`, return `False`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check a string for specific characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188792/how-to-check-a-string-for-specific-characters)

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in checking that a string `s` consists only of symbols from `t = "!@#$%^&*()_+[]{}'\"|./?><"`, then you can do something like:

```py
t = set(t)

all(c in t for c in s)  # This will be True if s consists only of symbols from t
```

EDIT: Improved the code according to @rioV8 's comment

Comment: Why do you need to convert it into a set? `in` works for strings as well.

Comment: @the-myth , true, but it's more efficient for sets: O(1) as opposed to O(n) (since python's set is a hashset). It probably won't make that much of a difference with such small strings, but there's certainly no harm in it

Comment: why convert to a list first before iteration, why not use a generator expression, `all` will terminate faster

Comment: @rioV8 that's a good point, actually

Answer (score 1):

Here's my code:

```py
def check_pwd(pwd):
    symbols = "!@#$%^&*()_+[]{}'\"|./?><" # \" instead of "
    if all(char in symbols for char in pwd): # checks if all characters of pwd in symbols
        return False
    return True

print(check_pwd("##"))
```

You could also shorten your code into:

```py
symbols = set("!@#$%^&*()_+[]{}'\"|./?><")

def check_pwd(pwd):
    return not all(char in symbols for char in pwd)
```

See the documentation for [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

Comment: why don't you use a `"""` or `'''` string

Comment: You could simply `return not all(...)` -- a branch statement isn't necessary here when the expression you're checking is a boolean value.

Comment: @ddejohn Yes I know, but I wanted them to understand how exactly the code is functioning.

Comment: @rioV8 I see no problem in the normal `"`. It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: you don't have to escape the `"`

Comment: That doesn't look like a problem to me.