# Python regex: find lines where period is missing in

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression, implemented in Python, that will match on this text

```
WHERE PolicyGUID = '531B2310-403A-13DA-5964-E2EFA56B0753'
```

but will not match on this text

```
WHERE AsPolicy.PolicyGUID = '531B2310-403A-13DA-5964-E2EFA56B0753'
```

I'm doing this to find places in a large piece of SQL where the developer did not explicitly reference the table name.  All I want to do is print the offending lines (the first WHERE clause above).  I have all of the code done except for the regex.

Comment: What have you tried? `WHERE PolicyGUID = '531B2310-403A-13DA-5964-E2EFA56B0753'` would do it.

Comment: Why not just use [the in operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-method)?

Comment: The lines will be in a similar format but will not all be related to PolicyGuid. They will be in the form of a WHERE clause where the term before the equals sign does not contain the reference to a table. So, it will not contain a period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
re.compile('''WHERE [^.]+ =''')
```

Here, the [] indicates "match a set of characters," the ^ means "not" and the dot is a literal period.  The + means "one or more."

Was that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
WHERE .*\..* = .*
```

not sure how accurate can be, it depends on how your data looks... If you provide a bigger sample it can be refined

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work in java, c#, javascript, I suppose you can adapt it to python:

`/WHERE +[^\.]+ *\=/`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l
["WHERE PolicyGUID = '531B2310-403A-13DA-5964-E2EFA56B0753' ", "WHERE AsPolicy.P
olicyGUID = '531B2310-403A-13DA-5964-E2EFA56B0753' "]
>>> [line for line in l if re.match('WHERE [^.]+ =', line)]
["WHERE PolicyGUID = '531B2310-403A-13DA-5964-E2EFA56B0753' "]
```