# how to register a user with a specific email address Django?

Tags: django, email, registration

How do I register a user with a specific email address?

```
def register(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST["username"]
    email = request.POST["mail"]

    # Ensure password matches confirmation
    password = request.POST["password"]
    confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
    if password != confirmation:
        return render(request, "auctions/register.html", {
            "message": "Passwords must match."
        })
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? And what is `request.POST.include["mail"]` supposed to do??

Comment: typo=> no "include" ...just mail . I want to let users to register with a specific domain...

Comment: can you fix the code and make sure it's working?

Comment: fixed! Please be kind to assist

Comment: See [Verify the domain of an e-mail address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369840/verify-the-domain-of-an-e-mail-address). Though if you use a form there should be a better way by specifying the `allowlist` for the [EmailValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/#emailvalidator)

Comment: Exactly, what do you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

"allowlist¶
Allowlist of email domains. By default, a regular expression (the domain_regex attribute) is used to validate whatever appears after the @ sign. However, if that string appears in the allowlist, this validation is bypassed. If not provided, the default allowlist is ['localhost']. Other domains that don’t contain a dot won’t pass validation, so you’d need to add them to the allowlist as necessary" .

DOCUMENTATION DOCUMENTATION
[validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/)

and a "dirty way" is =>

```html
<input id="email" type="email" pattern="[a-z.]*[@]\bfoo.com" required>
```