# regular expression to contain all strings that don't contain a pattern

Tags: regex

I have a pattern 'NewTree' and I want to get all strings that don't contain this pattern 'NewTree'. How do I use regex to do the filter?

So if I have 1.BoostKite 2.SetTree 3. ComeNewTreeNow

Then the output should be BoostKite and SetTree.
Any suggestions? I wanted regex that can work anywhere and not use any language specific function.

Comment: Are each of the keywords on a separate line or all together?

Comment: It is an array that has multiple Strings and I wanted to just find strings that don't have this pattern.

Comment: What language and why are you using regex for this?

Comment: And how come `SetTree` is not a match but `ComeNewTree` is?

Comment: python is fine. You want to match the complete string 'NewTree' so 'SetTree' does not contain 'NewTree'

Comment: But `ComeNewTree` is a match as you stated and it obviously contains `NewTree`?

Comment: You said Python, you mean a list?

Comment: Yes hwnd I made the correction.

Comment: Use [in operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-method) or [endsWith()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_endswith.htm) method instead of regex

Comment: I wanted regex that can work anywhere python, sql, unix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using a **Negative Lookahead** if you want to use a regular expression.

```
^(?!.*NewTree).*$
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oZ4zQ2/5)

Alternatively you can use the alternation operator in context placing what you want to exclude on the left, ( *saying throw this away, it's garbage* ) and place what you want to match in a capturing group on the right side.

```
\w*NewTree\w*|([a-zA-Z]+)
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oZ4zQ2/6)

In Python:

( *The strings being in list context, as you commented 'array' above* )

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'^(?!.*NewTree).*$')
>>> mylst = ['BoostKite', 'SetTree', 'ComeNewTree', 'NewTree']
>>> matches = [x for x in mylst if regex.match(x)]
['BoostKite', 'SetTree']
```

If it is just a long string of multiple words and you want to ignore the words that contain `NewTree`

```
>>> s = '1.BoostKite 2.SetTree 3. ComeNewTreeNow 4. foo 5. bar'
>>> filter(None, re.findall(r'\w*NewTree\w*|([a-zA-Z]+)', s))
['BoostKite', 'SetTree', 'foo', 'bar']
```

You can do this without a regular expression as well.

```
>>> mylst = ['BoostKite', 'SetTree', 'ComeNewTree', 'NewTree']
>>> matches = [x for x in mylst if "NewTree" not in x]
['BoostKite', 'SetTree']
```

Comment: Nice detailed explanation, +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Match each word with the regex `\w+NewTree\b`. It returns `true` if it ends with `NewTree`

Use `i` modifier for case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])

---

Use `\w*` instead of `\w+` in above regex if you want to match for `NewTree` word as well.

If you are looking for contains `NewTree` then try this regex `\w*NewTree\w*\b`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this in general in the manner of the following example for your specific case:

```
^(([^N]|N[^e]|Ne[^w]|New[^T]|NewT[^r]|NewTr[^e]|NewTre[^e])+)?(.|..|...|....|.....)?$
```

So far what I have here is a near miss. It will not match any string that has substring `NewTree`. But it will not match every string that is free of the substring `NewTree`. In particular it will not match `Nvwxyz`.

Comment: Modified to permit all words shorter than NewTree, intentionally avoiding the use of curly braces.

Comment: You say "insane." I say "literally what the question asks for" so I'm still working on this answer. There are plenty of "regex" languages that don't provide negative lookbehind etc. etc.

Comment: I do agree with you =)