# How do I find which character "var in var" is in in python

Tags: python, search, python-3.x, character

How could I find out what character a variable is in variable.
I hope this doesn't sound too confusing.

What I'm trying to do is make a search engine.
I have a variable called "currentchar" which is an integar.

So what I'm trying to do is:

```
if s[i] in l[currentchar:]: #Just checking if a string is in a string...
    currentchar = (Figure out which char "s[i]" started at.)
```

So for example if `s[i]` is `"ph"` and `l[currentchar:]` is `"elephant"` I wan't `currentchar` to be set to `3` because `"ph"` started 3 characters through `"elephant"`.

I hope people understand what I'm trying to say.

Comment: You did not even try to find a solution for yourself, hu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Python have a string contains method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you are checking that the substring exists, use `index`

```
s = "elephant"
print (s.index("ph"))
3

if s[i] in l[currentchar:]: #Just checking if a string is in a string...
    currentchar = l[currentchar:].index(s[i])
```

Comment: @user1541397, no worries, if you are using index you want to make sure the substring exists or it will throw an error

Comment: Alternatively you could use `find`: `currentchar = l[currentchar:].find(s[i])`. Instead of an exception it returns -1 if `find` couldn't find it (so you need an `if` after it not before). Both `str.find` and `str.index` support a start parameter so another way would be to use `currentchar = l.index(s[i], currentchar)`.

Comment: @xZise, there is nothing wrong with the if check, if the string does not exist I imagine the OP does not want currentchar set to -1

Comment: I just wanted to point out that there is also `find`. I also noted that (s)he still needs an if and my second example with the start parameter is actually using `str.index`.