# Searching a sequence of characters from a string in python

Tags: string, python-3.x

I wanted to ask if there is any way of finding a sequence of characters from a bigger string in python? For example when working with urls i want to find `www.example.com` from `http://www.example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc`. If found, it should return True.

Or is there any other way to do so? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Python have a string contains method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-method)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `in` to test if one string is a substring of another.

```
>>> "www.example.com" in "http://www.example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc"
True
```

Comment: Okay thanks! It was this simple! I was actually trying to use a a.find(b) method which dint work!

Answer (score 1):

I'm showing another way to do this

```
>>> data = "http://www.example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc"
>>> key = "www.example.com"

>>> if key in data:
...     #do your action here
```

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways to do it:

```
>>> a = "http://www.example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc"
>>> b = "www.example.com"
>>> if a.find(b) >=0:            # find return position of string if found else -1
...     print(True)
... 
True
>>> import re
>>> if re.search(b,a):              
...     print(True)
... 
True
```