# Is there a method in Python 3 that can search for a character in string and returns a a boolean?

Tags: python-3.x

I know `.find()` can search for a specific character, but I need something that can return a boolean instead of the exact location of the the character.

Comment: Do you mean like `in`, e.g. `'y' in 'xyz'` returns `True`?

Comment: you could write one yourself . Shouldnt take more than 3-4 lines of code

Comment: A Google search of "python 3 check if character is in string" returns numerous hits, each of which answers your question in seconds. Did you even *try* to search for the answer before posting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Python have a string contains method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-method)

Answer (score 0):

Use the "in" operator.

```
> a = 'now is the time...'  
> b = 'time'  
> exists = a in b
```