# Finding characters in an array

Tags: python, arrays, string

Is there a way in Python where  if a letter matchs any letter in a word it carries on the code so

```
X=str(input("input a word"))
Word="hello"
If x= Word() 
    a=a+1
```

So if Is there a way to say if I put x as "h" or "e" it will do the section of code

Sorry I know this is vague and I'm really bad at Python.any help will be amazing

Answer (score 0):

Use `in`:

```
if x in Word:
    a = a + 1
```

Comment: So does this say if x is found anywhere in word it will do the if statement ?

Comment: Thankyou so much simple question but has helped a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

This is answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

The method is called "in"

In your example:

```
the_string = raw_input('Enter text here')
if 'hello' in the_string:
    a = a + 1
```

Comment: So what does raw_input mean aswell I keep seeing this around

Comment: raw_input just prompts the user for text at the console.