# how to find if an element from an array is a substring of a string?

Tags: python

Given a string `s = "Leonhard Euler"`, I need to find if an element in my surname array is a substring of s. For example:

```
s = "Leonhard Euler"
surnames = ["Cantor", "Euler", "Fermat", "Gauss", "Newton", "Pascal"]
if any(surnames) in s:
    print("We've got a famous mathematician!")
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a string contains substring method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Comment: That's not how `any` works. Try `if any(surname in s for surname in surnames):`

Comment: `if any(x in s for x in surnames)` ? keep in mind that this would pass `'Eu'` to also count as true. Better idea is to split your name into individual names and match exact words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to know which surname is in s you can do that using any and list comprehension:

```
if any(surname in s for surname in surnames):
    print("We've got a famous mathematician!")
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider `if any(i in surnames for i in s.split()):`.

This will work for both `s = "Leonhard Euler"` and `s = "Euler Leonhard"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use isdisjoint attribute of sets after splitting the string to list to check if the two lists casted to sets have any elements in common.

```
s = "Leonhard Euler"
surnames = ["Cantor", "Euler", "Fermat", "Gauss", "Newton", "Pascal"]

strlist = s.split()
if not set(strlist).isdisjoint(surnames):
    print("We've got a famous mathematician!")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "Leonhard Euler"
surnames = ["Cantor", "Euler", "Fermat", "Gauss", "Newton", "Pascal"]

for surname in surnames:
   if(surname in s):
       print("We've got a famous mathematician!")
```

Loops through each string in surnames and checks if its a substring of s

Answer (score 0):

Actually I didn't test the the code but should be something like this (if I understood the question):

```
for surname in surnames:
  if surname in s:
    print("We've got a famous mathematician!")
```

Comment: This implementation will print multiple times if there are multiple matches. I think that OP only wants it to print once, which means you would need to `break` out of the loop when you find a match.