# Use enumerate to find indices of all words with letter 'x'

Tags: python, python-3.x

How use enumerate to help find the indices of all words containing 'x'

Thank you

```
wordsFile = open("words.txt", 'r')
words = wordsFile.read()
wordsFile.close()
wordList = words.split()

indices=[]

for (index, value) in enumerate(wordList):
    if value == 'x':

print("These locations contain words containing the letter 'x':\n",indices)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a string contains substring method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Comment: How does splitting give you the index?

Comment: It turned out I just needed to use the append function. Thank you for your suggestion though!

Comment: Do you have one word per line? You also need `in` as unless the word was `x` then you would never get a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost complete:

```
for (index, value) in enumerate(wordList):
    if 'x' in value:
        indices.append(index)
```

This checks, for every single word, if there is an `x` in it. If so, it adds the index to `indices`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was very helpful of you.