# How can i remove all extra characters from list of strings to convert to ints

Tags: python, replace, string-conversion

Hi I'm pretty new to programming and Python, and this is my first post, so I apologize for any poor form.

I am scraping a website's download counts and am receiving the following error when attempting to convert the list of string numbers to integers to get the sum.
**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,015'**

I have tried .replace() but it does not seem to be doing anything.

And tried to build an if statement to take the commas out of any string that contains them:
[Does Python have a string contains substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Here's my code:

```
    downloadCount = pageHTML.xpath('//li[@class="download"]/text()')
    downloadCount_clean = []

    for download in downloadCount:
        downloadCount_clean.append(str.strip(download))

    for item in downloadCount_clean:
        if "," in item:
            item.replace(",", "")
    print(downloadCount_clean)

    downloadCount_clean = map(int, downloadCount_clean)
    total = sum(downloadCount_clean)
```

Comment: `.replace()` _returns a new string_ with the unwanted portions removed; it does not modify the existing string.  You'll have to reassign `item` to the _result_ of the function: `item = item.replace(",", "")`

Comment: Will assigning `item` work here? I think the loop copies it (it's a value type), so you would be changing something, but it wouldn't get written back to the list. I think you need to reference `downloadCount_clean[index]` to make the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are not mutable in Python. So when you call `item.replace(",", "")`, the method returns what you want, but it is not stored anywhere (thus not in `item`).

**EDIT :**

I suggest this :

```
for i in range(len(downloadCount_clean)):
    if "," in downloadCount_clean[i]:
        downloadCount_clean[i] = downloadCount_clean[i].replace(",", "")
```

**SECOND EDIT :**

For a bit more simplicity and/or elegance :

```
for index,value in enumerate(downloadCount_clean):
    downloadCount_clean[index] = int(value.replace(",", ""))
```

Comment: You'd be better off adding it into the original `downloadCount_clean.append`, which would keep the code cleaner later.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicities sake:

```
>>> aList = ["abc", "42", "1,423", "def"]
>>> bList = []
>>> for i in aList:
...     bList.append(i.replace(',',''))
... 
>>> bList
['abc', '42', '1423', 'def']
```

or working just with a single list:

```
>>> aList = ["abc", "42", "1,423", "def"]
>>> for i, x in enumerate(aList):
...     aList[i]=(x.replace(',',''))
... 
>>> aList
['abc', '42', '1423', 'def']
```

Not sure if this one breaks any python rules or not :)