# Python: Check if Any List Item In String, If So Assign Found Item to Variable

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension

I've the following list:

`my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']`

I've the following list of strings:

`my_strings = ['azz', 'bzz', 'czz']`

I'm doing the following to determine if any items of `my_list` are in contained within a item in `my_strings`:

```
for my_string in my_strings:
    if any(x in my_string for x in my_list):
        # Do Stuff
```

What's the best practice for retaining the `x` as found in `my_list` so that I might be able to then do the following:

```
#Do Stuff
new_var = my_string.split('x')[1]
```

The desired result would be able to assign `zz` to `new_var` by determining that `a` from my list was in `azz` from `my_strings`

Comment: Please provide an example of your expected result, your last sentences are not clear to me ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method
check here

Comment: @wen That's the end logic, but I'm trying to retain the `'blah'` to be able to check. Right now, using the `any()` function doesn't let me know which element was found to make that check, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple indeed, you can even do it in a beautiful one liner using [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) as follows:

```
new_var = [my_string.split(x)[1] for my_string in my_strings for x in my_list if x in my_string]
```

this returns for you 2nd element from all splits of all strings in `my_strings` in which there exists elements from `my_list`

Comment: That's great! That did away with my whole function, and returned the values as I was attempting. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `any` because you actually care about which one matches:

```
for my_string in my_strings:
    for x in my_list:
        if x in my_string:
            #Do Stuff
            my_string.split('x')[0]
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `any()` because you need to know *specifically* which element matches a certain string. Simply use a regular for loop instead:

```
>>> def split(strings, lst):
...     for string in strings:
...         for el in lst:
...             if el in string:
...                 yield string.split(el)[1]
... 
>>> 
>>> for string in split(['azz', 'bzz', 'czz'], ['a', 'b', 'c']):
...     print(string)
... 
zz
zz
zz
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say if you want to `split` first value of `my_string` with first value of `my_list`

```
my_string[0].split(my_list[0])
```