# Using a loop to extend program to handle multiple lines of input

Tags: python, loops

I'm new to programming and currently in school. I'm having an issue with an assignment where I need to create a loop for multiple inputs until the user enters q to end. Now this question as a whole assignment has been asked before linked here [Trying to hammer out this zylabs Lab but struggling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46620663/trying-to-hammer-out-this-zylabs-lab-but-struggling) and I have been following @Splatmistro list to complete the assignment for the most part. But, I only need help to understand what is missing from my code to work correctly.

```
input_comma = input('Enter input string: \n')
**if input_comma != 'q':**
    while ',' not in input_comma:
        print('Error: No comma in string.')
        input_comma = input()
        print('Enter input string: ')

split_input = input_comma.split(',')
print('First word:',split_input[0].strip())
print('Second word:',split_input[1].strip())
```

I know I need an IF statement before the while statement but the one I have doesn't seem to be working. I know I missing something but I just can't figure it out. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

EDITED: This is the intended output of the code im working on.

```
Enter input string: Jill, Allen
First word: Jill
Second word: Allen


Enter input string: Golden , Monkey
First word: Golden
Second word: Monkey


Enter input string: Washington,DC
First word: Washington
Second word: DC


Enter input string: q
```

My code will take and print the first input correctly but it will not proceed to loop for a 2nd, 3rd, or 4th input. This is what I was asking for help with.

Comment: Fix your indentation. Code under while blocks should be a level of indentation higher than the indentation of the while loop above it.

Comment: Sorry I did not have it spaced correctly above I edited it to resemble my code the best I could. This is my first post and I'm still learning how some things work.

Comment: Hi could you elaborate a bit more on what is not working? what is the intended function of your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).  While not answering your specific question, the strategies in that q&a will help you.

Comment: @Primusa I need the code to list 4 inputs. Three of them are two-word phrases separated by a comma and the 4th is the letter q to end the program. I will edit the post to include the overall result I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @wwii I have looked over "Asking the user for input until they give a valid response" but I'm still not seeing whats missing. It may be that I did fully understand python yet, but I don't have an issue with the actual input just the looping output of multiple responses. I will continue to read through the thread in case I missed something. Thank you

Comment: How about @Jono2906's answer?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an `if` statement, use another `while` loop, like so:

```
input_comma = input('Enter input string: \n')
while input_comma != "q":
    while "," not in input_comma:

        print('Error: No comma in string.')
        input_comma = input()
        print('Enter input string: ')

    split_input = input_comma.split(',')
    print('First word:',split_input[0].strip())
    print('Second word:',split_input[1].strip())
    input_comma = input('Enter input string: \n')
```

Note that I also indented the last three lines...that makes the program work according to the example post you supplied.

Comment: You risk an infinite loop without asking (again) for an input string within the outer loop. Did you test it?

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realise that.

Comment: This has helped put me in the right direction. I can now output multiple inputs. Thanks. Now to just get the 4th output line to list q.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed Code:

```
input_comma = input('Enter input string:\n')
while input_comma != "q":
    while "," not in input_comma:

        print('Error: No comma in string.\n')
        input_comma = input()
        print('Enter input string:')

    split_input = input_comma.split(',')
    print('First word:',split_input[0].strip())
    print('Second word:',split_input[1].strip())
    input_comma = input("\n"'Enter input string:\n')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).