# Is it possible to get all element in a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a function that returns the arrays that are in a list according to the search?

For example I want to get the list of tables containing the letter A

```
myLst = [[ABC], [BCV], [BAD]]
return [[ABC], [BAD]]
```

Do I have to make my own function ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Next question please.

Comment: You can use a list comprehension, something like `return [x for x in myLst if 'A' in x]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Comment: If the contents of the list are strings, use `''` when adding them in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do in one line :

```
print([item for item in myLst for sub_item in item if 'A' in sub_item])
```

output:

```
[['ABC'], ['BAD']]
```

or as you said you want a function so here is the detailed solution :

```
def return_list(list_1):
    result=[]
    for item in list_1:
        if isinstance(item,list):
            for sub_item in item:
                if 'A' in sub_item:
                    result.append(item)
    return result

print(return_list(myLst))
```

Answer (score 0):

Very possible, and simple, just do as follows

```
if x for x in list if 'a' in x:
     #Do something
```

It's simple list comprehension, I recommend reading [Python MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Drafts/Python) before starting to code