# How to find an item in a list that exists as a sub-string in all the items of a list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, substring

I have a list of short strings, and a list of multiple long strings.
I would like to iterate through the short strings list and find which of the short strings is in **all** the items of a certain list.
for example:

short_str_list = ["aga", "ttt", "aca"]

seq_list = ["atcgcgtacat", "acatcgggattt", "tttacagtgtgtggg"]

the result should be:
"aca"

Can someone help me with the python script for it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break down the problem into pieces.

Start off by making a function that checks if **one** string is in a sequence of strings:

```
def check_one(string, seqs):
    for seq in seqs:
        if string not in seq:
            return False
    return True
```

Then make a function that checks **all** strings by using this function:

```
def check_all(strings, seq):
    result = []

    for string in strings:
        if check_one(string, seq):
            result.append(string)

    return result
```

Then simply call `check_all()`:

```
short_str_list = ["aga", "ttt", "aca"]
seq_list = ["atcgcgtacat", "acatcgggattt", "tttacagtgtgtggg"]

print(check_all(short_str_list, seq_list))
# ['aca']
```

You can also use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) , [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) and list comprehensions to to do this in one line:

```
print([x for x in short_str_list if all(x in y for y in seq_list)])
# ['aca']

print(list(filter(lambda x: all(x in y for y in seq_list), short_str_list)))
# ['aca']
```

Answer (score 0):

The following double loop expression does it:

```
print([ss 
       for ss in short_str_list
       if all(ss in ls for ls in seq_list)
       ])
```