# Find a string inside another string using re

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I know this question has been asked before but earlier today I found the following code in SO:

```
import re   

def findIfWordMatch(w):
    return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search
```

For example if I use the following strings the function return a match object if text1 is found in text2  (otherwise the function return None):

```
text1 = 'DIBUJO'
text2 = 'DIBUJO B308'
```

So to know if text1 is in text2 I do the following:

```
if(findIfWordMatch(text1)(text2) is not None):  
    #doSomething()
```

And it has been working well until I used these variables:

```
text1 = 'INT.EST.C.S.'
text2 = 'INT.EST.C.S. B308'
```

Im almost sure it has nothing to do with the dots because I have other variables with a similar structure and in works just fine so..

I would like to know why is this happening or another way to find if a string is inside another.

Thanks in advice

Comment: Actually you do not even need regex for that since there is a native operator `in` that does exactly what you are trying to implement...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method Don't reinvent the wheel bro! ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
'INT.EST.C.S. B308'
            ^^
```

Together dot and space `'. '`, in regex equivalent to `\W\W`, are not considered a part of word boundary `\b` `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`. Use negative lockahead `(?<!)(?!)`.

**Regex**: [`(?<!\S){0}(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/sK4DDu/1)

Comment: I was still unsure as to why it did not work despite knowing how to make it work. Well spotted.

Comment: Why is it that when we use a string without escaping the `dots` in compiling the `regex` it still matches the `dots` shouldn't it be taken as `match anything`.

Comment: Compensating :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead.

```
text1 = 'INT.EST.C.S.'
text2 = 'INT.EST.C.S. B308'

if text1 in text2:
  print("yes!")
```

Answer (score 0):

The dot `'.'` is used to match any character. So your pattern matches more than it should.

You can either format your pattern correctly by escaping the dots.

```
text1 = r'INT\.EST\.C\.S\.'
```

Or since this is a simple pattern you can use `in` to check if `text1` is contained in `text2`

```
if text1 in text2:  
    #doSomething()
```

Comment: That is a hack and will work in this specific case only. How does one escape the dots automatically according to the value in the variable `w` in `findIfWordMatch()`.

Comment: This is not a hack, it is simply formatting your pattern correctly. `findIfWordMatch` should only be used if a pattern has to be matched, thus the user should know they have to provide a pattern. If it is not, then `in` should be used.