# Very new to Python and need guidance

Tags: python, python-3.x

interactive input prompt to open browsers...(will print something instead for now).

```
chrm = ['Google Chrome', 'Chrome']

input("type a browser..: ")
if chrm[0:1] == input():
     print("starting: " + chrm)
```

What my intention is for this little thing is for a person to write one of the two possible input options..."Google Chrome" or "Chrome" to get a certain response. like openfile or printing something. but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: please, read [ask], review the [tour] and improve your title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should assign the returning value of `input()` to a variable, and use the `in` operator to test if it is one of the values in the `chrm` list:

```
chrm = ['Google Chrome', 'Chrome']

i = input("type a browser..: ")
if i in chrm:
     print("starting: " + i)
```

Comment: Have an upvote for reminding me about the `in` operator :D