# I am trying to append a line of Text to a list

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

```
Seq = []
Head = []

for line in range (0, len(text)):
   if line in '>':
      Head.append(line)
   else:
      Seq.append(line)
```

I am trying to append the header of FASTA sequences and the nucleotide sequence and separate them on a list. 
I don't know how to say that if line has '>', add to Head, else add to Seq

Comment: You're on the right track with [the ```in``` operator.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3437070/792238). Might need to flip the if condition.

Comment: To test if `'>'` is in the text use: `'>' in text`.  For example: `if '>' in text: ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line: `line in '>'` is testing whether `line` can be found inside the string `'>'`. You need to swap them around to `'>' in line`. This will test if the string `'>'` can be found inside `line`. If you are trying t test if the first character of line is `'>'`, use `'line[0] == '>'`.

Also when using range the start will default to zero so you could say `for x in range(len(text))`

Final code:

```
Seq = []
Head = []

for line in range (len(text)):
   if '>' in line:
      Head.append(line)
   else:
      Seq.append(line)
```