# How to search multiple items in a xlsx sheet in python

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize

I'm taking input from the user and then tokenizing it, tokenization is successful but the problem i'm facing is it does not display anything

i am trying to search the words in xlsx file which user inputs and then it should display that complete row in which that specific word exists.

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from xlrd import open_workbook
from nltk import word_tokenize


sen = input("Enter your sentence: ")
sent = word_tokenize(sen)
print(sent)


book = open_workbook("Pastho dictionary.xlsx")
for sheet in book.sheets():
    for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
        row = sheet.row(rowidx)
        for colidx,cell in enumerate(row):
            for i in sent:
                if cell.value == sent:#row value
                    print ("Found Row Element")
                    print(rowidx, colidx)
                    print(cell.value)
                    print(row)
```

i expect all the input words to be searched and then display the entire row in which that word exists.

Comment: I would suggest you try => "if sent not in cell.value" instead of "if cell.value == sent" (or if cell.value not in sent)

Comment: thanks for the help man but it didn't worked

Comment: `sent` should expect to be a **list**, how can u compare **list** with **string**?

Comment: Not necesarily. If sent is a string then it can be treated as a list and it checks whether the substring is contained within that string. But maybe I misunderstood the question. 
(This is what I mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I will go:

```
import xlwings as xw

bookName = r'first.xlsx'
sheetName = 'Sheet1'

wb = xw.Book(bookName)
sht = wb.sheets[sheetName]

myCell = wb.sheets[sheetName].api.UsedRange.Find('pankaj')

print(myCell.address)
```

Credit: https://www.vitoshacademy.com/how-to-search-in-a-worksheet-with-python/