# How to check for multiple occurences of a substring in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a strings like this:

```
string1 = "foo_bar_of_foo"
string2 = "foo_bar"
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method) answer tells me how to check for an instance of "foo" in a string, but what if I want to check for exactly **n** instances of "foo" in a string?

for example:

```
#pseudo-code = find(2 instances of foo)

if "foo" in string1: 
    print("true") #this should print

if "foo" in string2:
    print("false") #this shouldn't print since string2 only has 1 instance of foo
```

I can think of long and complicated ways of doing this, but I was wondering what the *pythonic* approach would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `str.count`:

```
string1 = "foo_bar_of_foo"
string2 = "foo_bar"

if string1.count('foo') == 2: 
    print("true")

if string2.count('foo') == 2:
    print("false")
```