# Check if sequence of variable str+int+int is contained in string

Tags: python, substring

Python noob here. 
I have the following issue, there is a string which contains an episode of a series like this: `"whatever S01E02 sowhat"` 
where series (01) can assume any value(01 until 99), and episode (02) also (01 until 99).. and I want to find this in the string.
I would like to use a clever way like 
if string contains a sequence of `str(S)+int+int+str(E)+int+int` then...
but all I did implement was a list containing all possible series (ij in the code) and episodes (kl in the code) and looped to create a list...

Does someone knows how to make this verification if a string contain a sequence of `alphabetic+int+int+alphabetic+int+int`?

I found the following post 
[Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)
to find substrings, but I couldn't adapt to have what I want.

I would like to search for a substring (`"S"+int+int+"E"+int+int`)
where these ints may have any integer value in a clever way.

below is my implemented code:

```
series_episode = "Series whatever S01E04 formating no-one-cares"
list_SijEkl = []
i,j,k,l=0,1,0,1
while i < 2:
    while j < 10:
        k,l=0,1
        while k<3:
            while l<10:

list_SijEkl.append("S"+str(i)+str(j)+'E'+str(k)+str(l))

                l+=1
            l=0
            k+=1
        j+=1
    i+=1

#print(list_SijEkl)

for episode in list_SijEkl:
    if episode in series_episode:
        cut = series_episode.split(episode)
        before = cut[0]
        after = cut[1]
        print('cut before '+ before)
        print('cut after'+ after)
        print (before + episode)
        print ('what i want in the end: '+before + episode)
```

Comment: You can use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) e.g. [`S(\d\d)E(\d\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/XXT7Dg/1) or [`S(\d+)E(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/T9fczF/1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regex for this. The following will find all occurrences in the string:

```
import re 

s = "Series whatever S01E04 formating no-one-cares"
re.findall('.+(S[0-9]{2}E[0-9]{2}).+', s)
```

More info on regex can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: perfect! Thank you for introducing this to me. appreciate John.

Comment: @T.Novais No problem. Happy to help. Could you please mark the answer as accepted if this answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use try-except method in this case. You check each word in the line,then:

```
if len(word)==6:
     if word[0]=='S' and word[3]=='E':
          try:
              a=int(word[1:3])
              b=int(word[3:])
              print(word,' found')
          except:
              pass
```