# Extract keywords/phrases from a given short text using python and its libraries

Tags: python, nlp, match-phrase

From a user given input of job description, i need to extract the keywords or phrases, using python and its libraries. I am open for suggestions and guidance from the community of what libraries work best and if in case, its simple, please guide through.

Example of user input:

`user_input = "i want a full stack developer. Specialization in python is a must".`

Expected output:

`keywords = ['full stack developer', 'python']`

Comment: Where are the keywords defined? Have you made an attempt that you can share with us?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Comment: Its a dict format and dict keys are the keywords.

Comment: will post my code shortly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a good keywords set is a good method. But, the key is how to build it. There are many way to do it.

Firstly, the simplest one is searching open keywords set in the web. It's depend on your luck and your knowledge. Your keywords (likes "python, java, machine learing") are common tags in Stackoverflow, Recruitment websites. Don't break the law!

The second one is IR(Information Extraction), it's more complex than the last one. There are many algorithms, likes "TextRank", "Entropy", "Apriori", "HMM", "Tf-IDF", "Conditional Random Fields", and so on.

Good lucky.

For matching keywords/phases, `Trie Tree` is more faster.

Answer (score -2):

Well, i answered my own question. Thanks anyways for those who replied.

```
keys = ['python', 'full stack developer','java','machine learning']
keywords = []
for i in range(len(keys)):
    word = keys[i]
    if word in keys:
        keywords.append(word)
    else:
        continue
print(keywords)
```

Output was as expected!