# What is the fastest way to check whether a cell contains letters?

Tags: python, pandas, contains

I have a dataset with 2.6 million rows in which I have one column called  `msgText`, which contains written messages.

Now, I want to filter out all messages that don't contain any letters. To do so I found the following code:

```
dataset = dataset[dataset['msgText'].astype(str).str.contains('[A-Za-z]')]
```

However, after 16 hours the code is still running.

Furthermore, based on [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method) I thought about creating a list of length 26, that contains all the letters in the alphabet and then check whether each cell contains that letter. But that does not seem efficient either.

Therefore, I am wondering if there is a faster way to find whether a cell contains letters.

---

EDIT: The code above works pretty well. Apparently, what I had in my (slow) code was: `dataset['msgText'] = dataset[dataset['msgText'].astype(str).str.contains('[A-Za-z]')]`

Comment: I actually tested your code and it takes about 5-6 seconds to complete with the following dataframe: `df = pd.DataFrame({'msgText': ['aasad dasd ', 'bdsd e ', 'ggre qew ', '1 1 1 ']*2600000})`

Comment: Do your strings have spaces or special characters in them? or is it alway something like `'12adwf1231'` or `'123'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas

dataset['columnName'].apply(lambda x: x.find('\\w') > 0)
```

Comment: This does not give an error, but does not work either. After: `dataset['msgText'].iloc[0] = '?!)'`, I ran your code and it ouputs `False`, just like for cells that do contain letters

Comment: Ok, I cannot test it, but the trick is the lambda function. You can also extract it in a method that takes the value as an attribute and then return whatever you want from it. now it returns a boolean value that probably is ignored, that's why it doesn't do anything. you can also use regex: https://www.w3schools.com/python/showpython.asp?filename=demo_regex_seq8

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy's [`isalpha()`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.isalpha.html#numpy.core.defchararray.isalpha) method. (Numpy is supposedly faster than pandas)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'msgText': ['a', 'b', 'g', '1']})
column = df['msgText']
column[column.str.replace(' ','').str.isalpha()]
```

Would return:

```
0    a
1    b
2    g
Name: msgText, dtype: object
```

**Test case with 2.6 mil rows:**

import datetime

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'msgText': ['a', 'b', 'g', '1']*2600000})
column = df['msgText']
start = datetime.datetime.now()
new_col = column[column.str.replace(' ','').str.isalpha()]
end = datetime.datetime.now()
print(f'Time taken: {end - start}; Shape: {new_col.shape}')

OUTPUT:
Time taken: 0:00:06.144576; Shape: (7800000,)
```

Comment: This code also deletes cells that contain both letters as well as numbers/other characters.