# How to match if a string is inside another string

Tags: python, python-3.x

basically I need to find if a string (actually a Path) is inside a similar string but more long.

I have this string in a list:

```
/aa/bb/cc
/aa/bb/cc/11
/aa/bb/cc/22
/aa/bb/dd
/aa/bb/dd/33
/aa/bb/dd/44
```

I expect to put inside a list only string like:

```
/aa/bb/cc/11
/aa/bb/cc/22

/aa/bb/dd/33
/aa/bb/dd/44
```

I need a new list without /aa/bb/cc and /aa/bb/dd because exists /aa/bb/cc/11 and /aa/bb/cc/22, same for /aa/bb/dd, exists /aa/bb/dd/33 and /aa/bb/dd/44 so I do not want the base form /aa/bb/cc and /aa/bb/dd.

I hope I was clear :-D

How can I do thet in Python 3?

Regards

Comment: Use `str.find(str, beg=0, end=len(string))` method determining if string str occurs in string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular expressions.

```
import re

list_1 = ["/aa/bb/cc",
    "/aa/bb/cc/11",
    "/aa/bb/cc/22",
    "/aa/bb/dd",
    "/aa/bb/dd/33",
    "/aa/bb/dd/44"]

regex = re.compile(r'/aa/bb/cc/+.')
obj = filter(regex.search, list_1)
regex2 = re.compile(r'/aa/bb/dd/+.')
obj2 = filter(regex2.search, list_1)
print(list(obj))
print(list(obj2))
```

Output:

['/aa/bb/cc/11', '/aa/bb/cc/22']

['/aa/bb/dd/33', '/aa/bb/dd/44']

Comment: Thank you so much!
This is exactly what I was looking for