# Check if string only contains characters from list of characters/symbols?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I check in Python 3 that a string contains only characters/symbols from a given list?

Given:

- a list `allowedSymbols = ['b', 'c', 'z', ':']`
- an input string `enteredpass = str(input("Enter"))`

How do I check if `enteredpass` only contains characters from the list `allowedSymbols`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa and everyone: this is different. The OP has a **list** of `allowedSymbols = ['b', 'c', 'z', ':']`. Not another string `allowedSymbols = 'bcz:'`

Comment: Subeen, please **don't call a list an array** (even if [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp) confuses the terminology for learners). Also, it would help your question not get wrongly closed as duplicate if you had showed an actual example list: `allowedSymbols = ['b', 'c', 'z', ':']` or whatever.

Comment: Last tip about asking a question is instead of `enteredpass = str(input("Enter"))`, show us some example (positive and negative) inputs: `enteredpass1 = 'b:c::z:bc:'`, `enteredpass2 = 'bc:y:z'`

Comment: @smci Well, converting one into the other is trivial. And when iterating over any of them they behave the same.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa: **No they don't behave the same:** if allowedSymbols is instead a list of words, e.g. `['in', 'the', 'car']`, then `all(c in allowedSymbols for c in 'carpeting')` will be False! That's why I'm saying "testing a string against a list of (possibly multicharacter) symbols is different to just testing its letters". Hence, **"Check a string contains another string"** is a broad and vague spec, and that's why we need specific examples to make it MCVE.

Comment: @smci I was talking about the explicit case here and not the general one. But I see your valid point.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa: actually I should have given the example `all(c in allowedSymbols for c in 'carinthe') = False`. But yeah there is a conflict between the specific intent of the OP (for single symbols, don't use a list, just use a string) and the general intent of the question as stated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The more Pythonic way is to use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=all#all), it's faster, shorter, clearer and you don't need a loop**:

```
allowedSymbols = ['b', 'c', 'z', ':']

enteredpass1 = 'b:c::z:bc:'
enteredpass2 = 'bc:y:z'

# We can use a list-comprehension... then apply all() to it...
>>> [c in allowedSymbols for c in enteredpass1]
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]

>>> all(c in allowedSymbols for c in enteredpass1)
True
>>> all(c in allowedSymbols for c in enteredpass2)
False
```

Also note **there's no gain in `allowedSymbols` being a list of chars instead of a simple string: `allowedSymbols = 'bcz:'`** (The latter is more compact in memory and probably tests faster too)

But you can easily convert the list to a string with `''.join(allowedSymbols)`

```
>>> allowedSymbols_string = 'bcz:'

>>> all(c in allowedSymbols_string for c in enteredpass1)
True
>>> all(c in allowedSymbols_string for c in enteredpass2)
False
```

Please [see the doc for the helpful builtins `any()` and `all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=all#all), together with list comprehensions or generator expressions they are very powerful.

Answer (score 3):

Use sets for membership testing: keep the symbols in a set then check if it is a superset of the string.

```
>>> allowed = {'b', 'c', 'z', ':'}
>>> pass1 = 'b:c::z:bc:'
>>> allowed.issuperset(pass1)
True
>>> pass2 = 'f:c::z:bc:'
>>> allowed.issuperset(pass2)
False
>>> allowed.issuperset('bcz:')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
for i in enteredpass:
    if i not in allowedSymbols:
         print("{} character is not allowed".format(i))
         break
```

Not sure what you're looking for with the Score = score -5.
If you want to decrease score by 5 if all entered characters are in the allowedSymbols list just put score = score - 5 on the same indentation level as the for loop, but at the end of the code after the if block.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a python expert, but something below will work

```
 for c in enteredpass:
   if c not in allowedSymbols: 
      return 0
```

Comment: `any()` is more Pythonic