# str.contains pandas returns 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

Tags: python, pandas

I am analyzing tweets.

I have 10k tweets and am interested in a list of words occurring:

```
lst1=['spot','mistake']
lst1_tweets=tweets[tweets['tweet_text'].str.contains('|'.join(lst1))].reset_index()
```

I want to double check and have:

```
f=lst1_tweets['tweet_text'][0]
f='Spot the spelling mistake Welsh and Walsh. You are showing picture of presenter Bradley Walsh who is alive and kick'
type(f)
<class 'str'>
```

I used

```
f.str.contains('|'.join(lst1))
```

returns:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

also

```
f.contains('|'.join(lst1))
```

returns:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

Any suggestions how I can search for a list of words in a string

Comment: You can only use `.str.contains()` on a Pandas series, not after extracting an individual string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Comment: Here your `f` is referencing a Python string, whose class is named `str`: `type(f) is str`. `pandas.Series.str` is a different class with different attributes, including `contains`. You can check if a class has an attribute by a certain name (without raising an Exception, that is) with the built-in callable `hasattr`

Answer (score 44):

I think you are looking for `in`:

```
if 'goat' in 'goat cheese':
    print('beeeeeeh!')
```

Comment: This could be a problem because list of strings he's searching for contains `'spot'` and `'mistake'`, but the string he's searching in contains `'Spot'` and `'mistake'`. Upper-case and lower-case characters are encoded differently, so the `in` operator for Python strings is case sensitive, and unlike `pandas.Series.str.contains`, you can't make the search case-insensitive.
I don't know this very well, but the `|` appears to be a regex character. `pandas.Series.str.contains` might be using the same syntax as what the Python module `re` does to search strings.

Comment: `if 'goat' in 'Goat cheese'.lower():` would do the trick then.

Comment: Looking up the pandas documentation, `pandas.Series.str.contains` does in fact use the `re` module. `.lower()` works too, but the `re` module could be more familiar.

Comment: @gosuto how can I tell when to use in and when to use str.contains ?

Comment: @R.A `str.contains` is a pandas thing, not python in general

Answer (score 14):

You might be confusing `.str.contains()` from pandas, which exists and is applied to series. In this case you can use `in` or `not in` operators. 
Here's a full guide on how to address the issue [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

From pandas docs:

> Series.str.contains(self, pat, case=True, flags=0, na=nan, regex=True).
>   Test if pattern or regex is contained within a string of a Series or Index.

Comment: exactly what happened to me!

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure if you're just checking for certain strings in a string, but i'm pretty sure .contains isn't a python thing, 
try this:

```
for "string" in f:
    # do whatever
```

Comment: He's not trying to loop over something, he wants to test for a substring

Comment: Also, the for-loop is assigns an object from an iterable to a variable per iteration. You can't assign objects to a string. This is likely intended to be an if-statement.