# How to search for specific word in a single line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to search for a particular word in a log file
For example,
   255    1237      92 D++

I want to scan through each line whether the word "D++" is present.
I have tried the approach below but failed.

```
if re.search(r"D\+\+", Line) is not None:
     print ("Success")
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Answer (score 1):

use 'in' keyword

```
if 'your_str' in line:
   print('Yeah')
```

Example:

```
>>> s = 'this has D++ string'
>>> if 'D++' in s:
...    print("OK")
...
OK
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not with `in`?

```
if 'D++' in Line:
    print ("Success")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strings .find

```
'255 1237 92 D++'.find('D++') > -1    
Out[329]: True

In [330]: '255 1237 92 D++'.find('sdf') > -1                                                                                                                                                               
Out[330]: False
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any mistake in your solution. You can simplify your code:

```
if re.search(r'D\+{2}', '255 1237 92 D++'):
    print('Success')
# Success
```