# How to check if URL contains something

Tags: python, selenium

I'm making a program which goes to a url, clicks a button, checks if the page gets forwarded and if it does saves that url to a file.

However, after a couple of entries the page blocks you from doing anything. When this happens the URL changes and you'll get this `Block.aspx?c=475412`

Now how'd I be able to check if the url contains `Block.aspx?c=475412` after each try?
I've tried looking for this but I could only find people asking how to get the current URL, not what I'm looking for, I need to check what the url contains.

Here is my code.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver


url_list = open("path')

try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\python\\chromedriver")
    for url in url_list:
       driver.get(url)
       send = driver.find_element_by_id("NextButton")
       send.click()

       if (driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[class='Error']")):
          print("Error class found")


except ValueError:
    print("Something went wrong checking the URL.")
```

I suppose I'd add an if statement checking if the URL contains `Block.aspx?c=475412`, if anyone would be able to help me out I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method -  the URL is a property of the WebDriver `driver.current_url`

Comment: Thanks this worked, however I don't know how to accept your answer.

Comment: i believe you look for a eventlistener, not a current_url

Comment: current_url worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to check what the URL contains, you can just use the `in` method built in with Python strings.

```
if "Block.aspx?c=475412" in driver.current_url: # check if "Block.aspx?c=475412" is in URL
    print("Block.aspx is in the URL")
```