# Python: How can I check between two strings that have repeating letters if string 1 is contained within string 2?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, duplicates, lowercase

```
def can_spell_with(target_word, letter_word):
    valid = True
    target_word1 = [x.lower() for x in target_word]
    letter_word1 = [x.lower() for x in letter_word]
    for c in target_word1:
        if c not in letter_word1:
            valid = False
        else:
            valid = True
    return valid
print(can_spell_with('elL','HEllo'))
# True
print(can_spell_with('ell','helo'))
# False
```

In the code above: I am trying to figure out how to return True if the letter_word contains the target_word.

So 'ell' in 'helo' would return False
But 'ell' in  'hello' would return True

Comment: does character case matter, upper case or lower case ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Comment: capitalization does not matter and thank you for the suggestion, there is quite some details in the explanations there thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `in`:

```
def can_spell_with(a, b):
     return (a.upper() in b.upper())
print(can_spell_with('Ell','HEllo'))
>>>True
print(can_spell_with('ell','helo'))
>>>False
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `in` but you first have to make the cases the same:

```
def can_spell_with(target_word, letter_word):
    return target_word.lower() in letter_word.lower()
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the first example. When you do `print(can_spell_with('Ell','HEllo'))`, the output is `False`, when it is true.

Comment: Should be "can_spell_with(letter_word, target_word)" This is doing "b in a" as opposed to "a in b"

Comment: Yeah @Michael, that's the problem

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll fix that

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a case-insensitive search. No need to do a list comprehension. Just use `lower()` or `upper()` to convert all characters to lower or uppercase and use `in`:

```
def can_spell_with(target_word, letter_word):
    return target_word.lower() in letter_word.lower()
```

Alternatively you could do a case insensitive regex search:

```
import re

def can_spell_with(target_word, letter_word):
    return re.search(target_word, letter_word, re.IGNORECASE) is not None
```

Answer (score 1):

```
target_word = target_word.lower() 
letter_word = letter_word.lower()

lenn = len(target_word)     
valid = False               

for i in range(len(letter_word)-lenn):   
    if letter_word[i:i+lenn] == target_word:   
        valid = True
return valid
```

Comment: How does this part work:
     
for i in range(len(letter_word)-lenn):   
        if letter_word[i:i+lenn] == target_word:

how does it know for 'ell' and 'helo' that the second 'l' is not there in 'helo'?

to me it looks like it searches for e in helo then l in helo then l in helo which works out to be true

Answer (score 1):

this will check the whether word1 in word2 irrespective of lowercase or uppercase

```
def func(word1, word2):
    first_char = word1[0]
    for index, char in enumerate(word2):
        if char==first_char:
            if word2[index:len(word1)+1]==word1:
                return True
    return False
```