# How to judge if a string contains a given substring (have gap)

Tags: python

e.g.

```
a = 'abc123def'
b = 'abcdef'
```

I want a function which can judge whether b in a.

```
contains(a,b)=True
```

p.s. gap is also allowed in the represention of b, e.g.

```
b='abc_def'
```

but regular expressions are not allowed.

Comment: something like ```if b in a:```?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Comment: That's OK. But I prefer not to use 'if b1 in a and b2 in a'.

Comment: @QuailWwk, is gap formed by a special character or digit as well?
Also, can you please provide more examples? This is confusing. Can `a` also have gaps? Does your current example represents the question well?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to check if the [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) of `a` and `b` is equal of the length of `b` (which is actually a lot simpler than finding the lcss).

Comment: @Namandeep_Kaur a have no gap. The gap have no specific pattern,. It can be digits, characters and punctuations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want to do is to check whether `b` is a [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) of `a`, you can write:

```py
def contains(a, b):
    n, m = len(a), len(b)
    j = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if j < m and a[i] == b[j]:
            j += 1
    return j == m
```

Comment: Thx! That's exactly what I need!

Answer (score -1):

Try using list comprehension:

```
def contains(main_string, sub_string):
    return all([i in main_string for i in sub_string])
```

NOTE: 'all' is a builtin function which takes an iterable of booleans and returns try if all are True.

Comment: @mobiusxs the question is asked for membership irrelavent of the order

Comment: @ViggyPiggy, Quite the opposite. It specifically ask if one is the other with a "gap" (extra substr) in it

Answer (score -1):

```
def new_contained(a,b):
   boo = False
   c = [c for c in a]
   d =  [i for i in b]
   if len(c)<=len(d):
     for i in c:
        if i in d:
          boo = True
   return boo
```

Comment: Doesn't even work for either example in the question

Comment: The string `ab` doesn't contain the string `ba`, with or without "gaps" (extra characters inserted), but your solution says it does