# Python: Search for partial string in a list

Tags: python

If I have a list:

```
mylist = ['super mario brothers',
          'animal crossing',
          'legend of zelda breath of the wild',
          'kirby superstar ultra']
```

Can I make `super mario brothers` to be printed if the user inputs `mario`, `legend of zelda breath of the wild` to be printed if user inputs `zelda`, and `kirby superstar ultra` to be printed if the user inputs `star`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Comment: Sure.  Can you please update the question to show what you’ve tried / researched so far; and specifically where you are stuck?

Comment: Since you are new you may not know, but if your question has been answered please accept the answer that has answered your question by giving it a tick, if the link in the comments answers your question then please close the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a string contains another string with `in`:

```
>>> 'mario' in 'super mario brothers'
True
```

So:

```
given_name = 'mario'

for sentence in mylist:
    if given_name in sentence:
        print(sentence)
```

Comment: I don't know that it's a dupe

Comment: "How can I tell if one string is contained in another?" is bound to be a dupe, it's such a basic question.

Answer (score 0):

Take the input as `ans`

Now iterate through your list, for each sentence in your list, see if the sentence contains `ans`, if so print the sentence.

```
mylist = ['super mario brothers', 'animal crossing', 'legend of zelda breath of the wild', 'kirby superstar ultra']

ans = input('Enter name')

for title in mylist:
    if ans in title:
        print(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in` operator.

I took the liberty of also adding case-insensitivity by lowercasing both the game name and the user input.

```
list_of_games = [
    "Super Mario Brothers",
    "Animal Crossing",
    "Legend of Zelda Breath of the Wild",
    "Kirby Superstar Ultra",
]
search_string = input("Search for a game:").lower()
for title in list_of_games:
    if search_string in title.lower():
        print(title)
```

As discussed in the comments, if you'd like to handle things differently depending on how many games match the input, we can change things e.g. so:

```
search_string = input("Search for a game:").lower()
# Build up a list of matching games using a list comprehension
matching_games = [title for title in list_of_games if search_string in title.lower()]
if not matching_games:  # the list is falsy if it's empty
    print("No matches for that input, sorry!")
elif len(matching_games) == 1:  # Only one match
    print("One match:", matching_games[0])
else:
    print("Multiple matches:")
    for title in matching_games:
        print("*", title)
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your kind reply. I was wondering if a user types in something completely unrelated to the titles in the list, is it possible to print something that tells the user that the game they have entered is not on the list? if I add a line "else: print("entered game is not on the list") "after print(title), the code just prints entered game is not on the list regardless of what I put in the input.

Comment: @kim Sure thing. I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

Or, just for a laugh ... here’s a one-liner:

```
[i if i.find('mario') > -1 else None for i in mylist][0]
```

Essentially, this checks each element in the list for the search string and returns the first matching list element if found; otherwise `None` is returned.

Answer (score -2):

You could use regex, iterating over all the elements in the list

Comment: You don't need a regexp to do a substring search.