# How to check if a Python string contains letters, numbers and '_' sign but nothing else?

Tags: python, string

I'd like to check if a Python string contains BOTH letter and number, but nothing else. In other words, strings like "A530", "D592" should return True, whereas strings like "ABCDE" (all letters), "000326" (all number), and "A339*加>" (alphanumeric but also has special characters) will return False.

I've seen a lot of sites that show how to check if string contains either letter or number, but not both. This site https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-check-if-a-string-has-at-least-one-letter-and-one-number/ shows how to check both letter and number, but they iterate through each character in the string, which is not very efficient and something I tried to avoid doing if possible.

Comment: We have hundreds of questions about regexes to enforce inane password requirements; did you search before asking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Comment: Your title mentions the `_` character, but the question body says nothing about it. It's not clear what your actual requirements are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution without regex :)

```
s=input()
print(not ((all(i.isdigit() for i in s) or (all(i.isalpha() for i in s)) or (any(not i.isalnum() for i in s)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If those string are individual strings, you can use a regex to check that:

```
import re

re.match("^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\d])[a-zA-Z\d]+$", "A530") # Will return an re.Match object
re.match("^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\d])[a-zA-Z\d]+$", "A339*加>") # Will return None
re.match("^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\d])[a-zA-Z\d]+$", "AAAA") # Will return None
re.match("^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\d])[a-zA-Z\d]+$", "0000") # Will return None
```

---

Comment: it seems running re.match("^\w+$", "623") will also return an re.Match object, but that string doesn't have letter in it.

Comment: @Stanleyrr Oh I misread, Let me quickly fix that for you and edit my post

Comment: @Stanleyrr Check out the updated version of the regex

Comment: Thanks, @Or Y. This is better, except re.match("^(?=.*[wa-zA-Z])(?=.*[\d])[\w]+$", "567A_") would also return the object even though it shouldn't (there's an underscore sign in the string)

Comment: @Stanleyrr Edited again, now it won't accept underscores.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't prefer regex then here is the way.

All conditions checked separately. It is Pythonic and readable as well.

Code:

```
import string

lst = ["A530", "D592", "ABCDE", "000326", "A339*加>"]
str_ascii_digits = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
passed = [s for s in lst if 
            any(ch in string.ascii_letters for ch in s ) and 
            any(ch in string.digits for ch in s) and 
            all((ch in str_ascii_digits for ch in s))]
print(passed)
```

Output:

```
['A530', 'D592']
```