# Python Comparison of Two lists

Tags: python, json, list, search, comparison

I am working on NLP project. I have extracted keywords from Resume and stored them in the list. The other list consists of all technical keywords which I have extracted from JSON. Both the lists consist of many keywords and below is just for reference.

```
list_of_keys=['azure', 'job', 'matlab', 'javascript', 'http', 'android', 'amazon', 'apache spark']

result=['apache http server', 'angularjs', 'azure bot service', 'amazon s3', 'android sdk', 'android studio', 'amazon cloudfront']
```

**Code:**

```
with open('rawtext.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
result = [x["name"].replace("@", " ").lower() for x in data]
print(result)

print ("List of Matched Keywords are:\n")
# Comparing Lists

for item in list_of_keys: 
    for item1 in result: 
        if item == item1: 
            print("Word from Resume: ", item, ", Word from JSON data: ", item1)
print ("****************\n")
```

**Current Output**

Word from Resume:  box , Word from JSON data:  box
Word from Resume:  arduino , Word from JSON data:  arduino
Word from Resume:  arduino , Word from JSON data:  arduino
Word from Resume:  browser , Word from JSON data:  browser
Word from Resume:  black , Word from JSON data:  black
Word from Resume:  address , Word from JSON data:  address
Word from Resume:  address , Word from JSON data:  address

I have tried above a very simple technique by comparing two lists that just matches exact words and prints them. However, what I want is if there is any match in two lists e.g if 'apache spark' gets matched with result list 'apache http server'
then it should print as an output: Word from Resume:  apache spark, Word from JSON data:  apache http server. Similarly, if amazon is matched then it should print as an output: Word from Resume:  amazon, Word from JSON data:  amazon s3, amazon cloudfront

**Required Output:**

Word from Resume:  apache spark, Word from JSON data:  apache http server
Word from Resume:  amazon,       Word from JSON data:  amazon s3, amazon cloudfront
Word from Resume:  http,          Word from JSON data:  apache http server

Can someone please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're trying to achieve is a bit different to a simple equality check, i.e. `'azure' == 'azure bot service'` will always return `False`.

The comparison check can be more sophisticated, but from your expected behaviour, I believe you're looking for this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

res_dict = defaultdict(list)
for item in list_of_keys: 
    for item1 in result: 
        if item in item1:
            res_dict[item].append(item1)

for k,v in res_dict.items():
    print("Word from Resume: ", k, ", Word from JSON data: ", ",".join(v))
print ("****************\n")
```

I've replaced the `=` check with the `in` check, which means that the comparison will return true if `azure` occurs inside `azure bot service` but will return false for all the other strings from the results array.

I would also suggest looking at [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method) for more complex substring matches since you're probably looking to check if words co-occur between your `list_of_keys` and `results` array.

Alternatively, you can also look at fuzzy search since it seems very close to your intended behaviour https://pypi.org/project/fuzzysearch/

Comment: It is printing this:
Word from Resume:  manage , Word from JSON data:  adobe experience manager
Word from Resume:  manage , Word from JSON data:  aws key management service
Word from Resume:  manage , Word from JSON data:  aws secrets manager
Word from Resume:  manage , Word from JSON data:  aws certificate manager

Comment: I am looking for fuzzy search. May be this will help me.

Comment: I was about to suggest fuzzy search. Good call. Please upvote the answer if it helped. I've edited my answer to include a link to a fuzzysearch library.

Comment: Sure, I will upvote. Could you please assist me in integrating the fuzzy search logic.

Comment: I think the following link should suffice to perform the check you want. https://towardsdatascience.com/fuzzy-string-matching-in-python-68f240d910fe

Just settle on a ratio or partial_ratio value that would be sound enough for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
common = list(set(list_of_keys) & set(result))
```

For instance:

```
list_of_keys = ['one','two','three','some more']
result = ['two','some more']

common = list(set(list_of_keys) & set(result))

print (common)
```

Output:

```
['two', 'some more']
```

Comment: it is printing the same output somehow.