# Zybooks 13.3.1 Challenge Activity

Tags: python

I am struggling on completing this zybook challenge activity and I don't know what else

Complete the if-else statement to print 'LOL means laughing out loud' if user_tweet contains 'LOL'.

Sample output with input: 'I was LOL during the whole movie!'
LOL means laughing out loud.

Comment: This question can be made better by adding details. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Answer (score 2):

What this is asking you to do is print "LOL means laughing out loud" if LOL is in the tweet (`if 'LOL' in user_tweet:`).

If the tweet does not have LOL (`else:`), print 'No abbreviation.'

This gives you the if-else statement:

```
if 'LOL' in user_tweet:
    print('LOL means laughing out loud.')
else:
   print('No abbreviation.')
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Pretty good first post. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`user_tweet = input()
if(user_tweet.find('LOL') != -1):
print('LOL means laughing out loud.')
else:
print('No abbreviation.')

Using the find function works as well. The find function is searching user_tweet for string placement index != (not equal) to -1. The find function returns the index of the first occurrence of item x in the string, else returns -1.

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this.

```py
user_tweet = input()

if(user_tweet.find('LOL') != -1):

    print('LOL means laughing out loud.')
else:
    print('No abbreviation.')
```

Answer (score -1):

if 'LOL' in user_tweet:

is the correct code for here

if LOL is in the the tweet it will output the abbreviation if not it will say not abbreviation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).