# Check if a list of string contains particular letter or charcater in it(python)

Tags: python, string, list, contains

How do we find a letter or special character present in list of strings?
I have a list and want to check if it contains particular letter in it. I tried to do but getting an error.

code:

```
lst = ['Mangos*','apples,'REd']
for l in lst:
    if l.contains('M') or l.contains('*'):
             print(l)
```

getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

Should we not use `contains`? or what should we to find if a string has particular letter or special character?

Comment: Instead of `l.contains('M')` why not use `'M' in l`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = ['Mangos*','apples','REd']
for l in lst:
    if 'M' in l or '*' in l:
             print(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find a specific letter in your string you can use a regular expression.
first, you need to import os and import re. Then we can create a loop for each match.

```
import os  
import re 

lst = ['Mangos*','apples','REd']

for l in lst:  
    find = re.findall("M",l)  
    if find:  
        print(l)
```

### Output

Mangos*