# Search Members Function

Tags: discord.py

Currently this function is searching for a member that starts with the input query. For example, if i input `ja`, it will output all members that have their names start with `ja`. However, i am trying to make it so it accounts for all names that have `ja` in their name. Hence, it will not only include `jack, jasper` but include `kaja, maja` etc.

```py
    @staticmethod
    async def search_members(guild, member) -> typing.List[discord.Member]:

        return [i for i in guild.members if str(i).lower().startswith(member.lower())]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `in` keyword.

```
@staticmethod
async def search_members(guild, member) -> typing.List[discord.Member]:

    return [i for i in guild.members if member.lower() in str(i).lower()]
```

NOTE: This looks up the Members username if you want the Nickname of the Member in this specific guild use `discord.Member.display_name`