# How can make discord.py bot to determine keyword in sentence?

Tags: python

I'm making a discord.py bot, and I want it to send a message when catch a keyword in a sentence or paragraph.
I know how to make a keyword command, but I don't know how to make it to determine a keyword inside words, can someone help me this problem?
That's my command:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.content == 'Good morning' and msg.author != bot.user:
        await msg.channel.send('Good morning boys:)')
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question? What you're saying is that a message can contain a sentence, like say "Hello, good morning everyone", and you want to be able to detect a substring, like say "good morning"? Do you have a problem with the detection, or with actually sending a message?

Comment: Nah, I want the command can detect a word in message, like it can find keyword "good 
Morning in "Hey every one, good morning", and then send a message to reply sender.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly from your comments, this is the question:

*You have a Discord Bot, and you want to detect when there's certain words in a message, like say "Hello World".
If a message has "Hello World" in it, then the bot sends a reply.*

Here's a small proof-of-concept:

```py
@bot.event 
async def on_message(msg):
  # For more details on how to detect when a string contains a substring in Python, 
  # refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method
  if "Hello World" in msg.content and msg.author != bot.user: 
    await msg.channel.send('Good morning boys:)')
```