# Is it possible to use comparison operators on an error?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, valueerror

I am doing something similar to this to output if a variable contains a substing.

```py
print("Variable contains foo" * variable.index("foo") !=None)
```

But when I run the program, I just get this error.

```
ValueError: substring not found
```

Of course, I am expecting variable to not contain "foo" sometimes, so is there any way to do something like this without using `try` and `except`?

Comment: If you just want to know if `variable` contains "foo" you can use `in`: `"foo" in variable`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Comment: using `if "foo" in variable: print(...)` is more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As  @IainShelvington already said you can use `'foo' in variable` which will never raise an Exception, or `not in` for opposite condition:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcyxCoAwEAPQ3a8ILrWOdfY33K@i9EDuSi2CX18RKYhugSQvnjmoDKUclJj8tmCEIayqpomJJXftVJtZJRPLfrctenTmnoEF9WxtU6N7IE/pBzkE2iH6cUTz23LWlnIB)

```
variable = 'a foo'
print("Variable contains foo" * ('foo' in variable))
variable2 = 'a bar'
print("Variable2 has no foo" * ('foo' not in variable2))
```

Output:

```
Variable contains foo
Variable2 has no foo
```

Comment: Wow how did I not think of that

Answer (score 2):

In despite of here present correct answers, I recommend more easy-readable and understandable variant without arithmetic operations on strings:

```
print('' if variable.find("foo") < 0 else 'Variable contains foo')
```

And don't forget about performance:

1. A IF in ELSE B → runtime 0.075396442~0.079946904

```
import timeit
start = timeit.default_timer()
variable = 'foo'
for i in range(0,1000000):
  a = 'Variable contains foo' if 'foo' in variable  else ''
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

2. IF in A*BOOL → runtime 0.098681301~0.099800959

```
import timeit
start = timeit.default_timer()
variable = 'foo'
for i in range(0,1000000):
  a = "Variable contains foo" * ('foo' in variable)
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

3. A IF find ELSE B → runtime 0.19235808~0.195008498

```
import timeit
start = timeit.default_timer()
variable = 'foo'
for i in range(0,1000000):
  a = '' if variable.find("foo") < 0 else 'Variable contains foo'
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's `find`, which returns -1 if the substring cannot be found:

```
print("Variable contains foo" * (variable.find("foo") != -1))
```

Note that this prints an empty line if "foo" is not present.

Answer (score 0):

The **index** method raises an error if the substring is not found, whereas the **find** method returns -1.

```
"My beautiful string".index("foo")     # This raises an exception

"My beautiful string".find("foo")     # This returns -1
```

Then, you could just save the result and print whatever you wish.